# EasyAdmin: is there any way to have entity's fileds when calling setTemplatePath method in easyadmin?

Tags: symfony4, easyadmin

Is there any way to get more than one filed of an entity  when calling **setTemplatePath()** method in easyadmin ?

for example :

I have an entity called OperatorSystem which has 3 properties : id, label and status.

I want to show operator label based on status flag. So in my twig file I need both label and status.

I tried to call entity.status but it doesn't work.

For now I can show in my twig the operator's name like this:

```
{% set operator = field.value|upper %}
```

But I need to have status for if else condition.

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
    yield TextField::new(SystemConstants::FIELD_OPERATOR_ID)
                ->setLabel(SystemConstants::FIELD_OPERATOR_LABEL)
                ->setSortable(false)
                ->setHelp(SystemConstants::FIELD_OPERATOR_HELP)
                ->setTemplatePath(UtilityConstants::OPERATOR_TEMPLATE_PATH);
```

Comment: Try `entity.instance.status` in the twig template.